# How do I establish if an op-amp is bad?

Tags: operational-amplifier, testing, test

[image]

I have a JRC2374 SOIC8 IC on my board which is not powering up.  The IC seems to be involved in the power regulation switching operation. Here are the internals from the datasheet:

[image]

I know little about op-amps but I'm trying to get this PCB reverse-engineered and find the fault. I get continuity from my multimeter across the input of the op-amp pins 6 and 7; I don't think it's right for a short to exist. Am I wrong?

Comment: Is the IC still in the circuit (that is, still soldered to the PCB)?

Comment: Is there a small resistance between the pins, or is it a dead short?

Comment: Is this one board from a production batch? Are you the designer or fixer?

Comment: Yes still in circuit but plan to remove pipe, John D no resistance and i'm the repairer

Comment: Photo added, top component markings are left 504 and right 16T2, the 2374a being the lower, Cap E2 removed so I could establish its traces. very lowest sot23 marked L4

Answer (score 2):

According to the [datasheet of the JRC2374,](https://docs.rs-online.com/15f9/0900766b80e6f656.pdf) you should expect a near short circuit between pins 6 and 7.

Pins 6 and 7 are used to measure current through a shunt resistor.  If you measure resistance from pins 6 to 7, you will be measuring the resistance of the shunt.

[image]

All the example circuits show the shunt resistor.

What ever is wrong with your PCB, the short circuit between pins 6 and 7 is not the cause.

Comment: I'm going to try to map the circuit on Kicad for futher info / sharing

Answer (score 1):

It's not an opamp, so opamps have nothing to do with this chip and measuring it. It's a PWM DC/DC converter chip.

You are also measuring mystery innards of a chip with a mystery multimeter, we don't know how your multimeter measures continuity, and what it considers between threshold of continuity and no continuity.

And in a circuit there will be a shunt resistor much less than an ohm between pins 6 and 7 so for sure it will show continuity and it will not measure if chip is OK or not.

Comment: Many thanks, i'll power it up and take some readings to see 1. what function its performing step up / down or inverting.  For now an image of the top side of the board.

Comment: Ok i have the IC off the board, the shut resistor is as expected 0.22 ohm, the IC has nothing between pins 6 & 7 not a dicky bird of resistance, any ideas?

Comment: No ideas, but this does not relate to the original question. This is now branching into a repair/debug question in the comment section. You might want to open a new question how to debug it.

Comment: is there a URL to that list please, I cannot seem to locate, or do you just mean title another post "debug"