# Help requested debugging this circuit I've reverse engineered

Tags: debugging

Following my last post ([How do I establish if an op-amp is bad?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/650695/how-do-i-establish-if-an-op-amp-is-bad)) I have now attempted to map out a schematic for the circuit I am really now struggling with.

Attached is the circuit diagram.  It is my first time preparing such a thing so likely there are mistakes.

The problem is that this device does not power up and resistor R82 was burnt and I do not know its value. What I have deduced so far:

- The device works on a 9 VDC supply. It drives servos to the beat of music.
- Q19 (a large component on a heat sink) looks to provide power for the servo.
- The trace is marked Vcc which looks to feed the transistor driven servo PCB with power through the ribbon connector FC2.
- IC2 seems to be a voltage regulator for the 9V.
- IC3 looks to step up to 12V for the other parts of the circuit, there is no 12V at the test point which suggests to me that IC13 is the culprit but I am not sure what component it is. It looks to me like an SOT753 or indeed could be SOT23-5 and is marked "504."  There are numerous datasheets for both SOTs.
- I've inserted this as a buck regulator but the pin out does not tally so that is probably a wrong guess on the component.
- The inserted picture shows the connection of the component.  The voltages I read are pin 2 9V, pin 4 1mv.  Oddly, the trace from pin 1 of FC2 is marked 6V not 9V although the power supply for the device is 9V DC (perhaps a board marking error.)

What would really help me as a novice is if somebody could firstly talk me through their view of the principle of how this power section of the board appears to be and secondly then help me take some further measurements and component test to determine the fault.

[image: servo driver toy]

Comment: Thank you, I think that got it, juggled things around abit and made fonts larger

Comment: Updated and improved schematic

Answer (score 1):

IC3 appears to be the [JRC2374](https://docs.rs-online.com/15f9/0900766b80e6f656.pdf) you asked about in your previous question.

That means that the pin names you have assigned to IC13 must be wrong:

[image]

Pin 4 of U3 is ground - that part agrees with the datasheet for the JRC2374.  You've got what looks like "Vout" and "CM" connected to ground - that's got to be wrong.  Additionally, you have the pin marked "GND" on U13 connected to something that is definitely not ground.

Making things harder to read is that you've got many of the electrolytic capacitors connected backwards, like the one circled above.  That one shouldn't be an electrolytic capacitor, any way.  The datasheet shows it to be 1.5nF so it is probably a small ceramic capacitor rather than a large electrolytic capacitor.

It would be interesting to see the voltages at the following marked points:

[image]

- Q19 seems to be there to switch Vcc on and off.
- Check U13, pin 4 to see what it is sending to Q19.

If R82 is really burned out, then I expect Q19 to be damaged as well as U13.

Comment: Many thanks i'll insert the components i removed to test off the board and take the measurements

Comment: Perhaps IC13 is a JRC NJU7706F31A2, as this system has DSP?  Some pins look like a better fit

Comment: It could be the [NJU7706F31A2](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/294/NJU7706_NJU7707_E-1917656.pdf).  The pins match.  I had thought it might be some kind of voltage supervisor but couldn't find a matching one.

Comment: Thanks JRE, pressumably if i simply remove it it will not hold the base of Q19 low and we'll have some Vcc?

Comment: You have to pull the base of Q19 low to get Vcc.

Comment: JRE, thats because its PNP?, I've updated the schematic was able to ascertain that R82 is 100ohm and that VCC should be 5v

Comment: Yes.  You pull the base of a PNP down to make it conduct between the emitter and collector.

Comment: Can anybody help further with this 504 component, I've also seen it labelled "50B"?  SO as mentioned it pulls Q19 low and i get how pin 2 is its supply and pin 3 its likely reference but what about 5 and 1 that are linked how do they influence pins 2 and 3 on IC3?  Looking at the internals of IC3 pins 1 and 2 look like they are emitter collector junction so pin 2 must be a power source right?

Comment: Entered the Q19 PNP transistor part only into Every Circuit App here https://everycircuit.com/circuit/6085768979939328 trying to determine how 6v Vcc is derrived, clearly component "504" seems to pull the base low, what am I missing please, other than the voltage drop of Q19 how could the Vcc be 6v could component 504 also drop the voltage perhaps?

Comment: Also I was rethinking the circuit application, so the original RN5RF voltage regulated via a PNP transistor, with various other features, over current etc. Is there any reason, if only to get the circuit working, I could not simply use a 5volt 1amp regulator such as L7805ACV to derive the 5V VCC from the Vdd of 9volts please?