# Help identifying a SOT23-5 or SOT753 marked "504" or ""50B"

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, components

[image: This componenent is used on the power side of an audio device which uses digital signal processing to move servos to music on a cartridge held digitally.]

Other IC's on the board seem to be from JRC. This componenent is used on the power side of an audio device which uses digital signal processing to move servos to music on a cartridge held digitally.

[image]

Comment: very minimal information in your post ... please show the immediate area around the IC and an overall view of the PCB

Comment: please see the following link jsotola  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/651526/help-requested-debugging-this-circuit-ive-reverse-engineered

Comment: the question should stand on its own, without relying on links to outside pages

Comment: I was asked to post in "debugging" section so I raised this a shown not realising its not a section but a tag, apologies i am learning the forum protocol

Answer (score 2):

Good databases: https://smd.yooneed.one/ http://www.s-manuals.com/smd

Seems to be Ricoh (now Nisshinbo?) R1191HxxxD series LDO.

Comment: Thanks Tim i'm getting closer, i've attached the link above to the schematic if you can review whether this IC is a better fit here please?

Comment: @Andyg doesn't seem like it.

Comment: I think it may be RN5RF50AA @Tim Williams what do you think? added pcb images. Also trying to identify that SOT89 guess its "16T"

Comment: @Andyg Possible. (Is this not about the "504" anymore?) If so, the "16T9" must be a PNP. Looks like a power input area; that diode, 1N5820 or so, polarity protection or is there a switching supply nearby?

Comment: Hello Tim Williams, the power supply is a mains adpator 9v which I assume is a switching supply